# Proof verification: If a set is connected, then it is an interval or a point

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, connectedness

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be connected, then it is an interval or a point.

Is my proof valid? I have included the conditions for a set to be disconnected below the proof.

By the contrapositive of the statement, assume that $A$ is not an interval and not a singleton. Since $A$ is not an interval, there exists $a_1, a_2 \in A$ (given that $|A| > 1$) and a $b \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $a_1 \leq b \leq a_2$ and $b \notin A$. Since $b \notin A$, $b \neq a_1$ and $b \neq a_2$, so $a_1 < b < a_2$. Define the open sets
\begin{align*}
    U = (- \infty, b) \text{ and } V = (b, \infty).
\end{align*}
To show that $A$ is disconnected, $U$ and $V$ must satisfy three conditions.

C1: Note that $U \cup V = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{b\}$, and since $b \notin A$, we have $A \subset (U \cup V)$, thus condition C1 holds.

C2: Since $a_1 < b$, $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$ because $a_1 \in U$. Likewise, since $b < a_2$, $A \cap V \neq \emptyset$ because $a_2 \in V$. Therefore, condition C2 holds.

C3: For $x \in (A \cap U)$, we have $x < b$ and for $y \in (A \cap V)$, $b < y$. Hence, for any pair $x,y$ we have that $x < y$, which implies that the sets are disjoint. Therefore, $(A \cap U) \cap (A \cap V) = \emptyset$, satisfying C3. We conclude that $A$ is disconnected.

**QED**

A set is disconnected if there exists a $U,V$, such that:

C1: $A \subset (U \cup V)$

C2: $A \cap U \neq \emptyset, A \cap V \neq \emptyset$

C3: $(A \cap U) \cap (A \cap V) = \emptyset$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof looks perfectly right. Just a couple of comments on it:

1. $C3$ could be seen more direclty by noting that $U \cap V = \varnothing$. In detail:

\begin{align} (A \cap U) \cap (A \cap V) &= A \cap (U \cap A) \cap V \\ &= A \cap (A \cap U) \cap V \\ &= (A \cap A) \cap (U \cap V) \\ &= A \cap \varnothing \\&= \varnothing. \end{align}

2. You probably just forgot this and you know it, but in the definition of disconnected set you need $U$ and $V$ to be *open* sets.
3. This is more of a grammar note: you should've wirtten "there *exist* $a_1, a_2 \in A$..." instead of "there *exists* $a_1, a_2 \in A$...". A similar comment applies in the definition of disconnected set.